# Alternative to ViewBag.Title in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

By default the new project template for ASP.NET MVC 3 adds the following to the default layout (masterpage in razor):

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

The view must then contain the following to assign the title of the page, for instance:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}
```

Perhaps it is just my own preference but I find that using the ViewBag to hold the title a little bit wrong (I'm thinking too much magic-string flavor). So my question is: Is this the recommended best practice for people using ASP.NET MVC 3 and razor (using a dynamic property bag) or are you opting for something more strongly typed (perhaps involving a custom baseclass?)

Comment: Using the viewbag for this is great as you can declare the variable in a layout page and then specify a different title for each view that inherits from it. There's really no other way to do it without using a statically typed model.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think there is any thing bad with default title handling feature that ships with asp.net MVC 3, its okay to do.

I personally do this(below written) to handle title, **I am not endorsing the below code** or saying that its better than default functionality, its just a preference.

Master

```
<title>
    @RenderSection("Title");
</title>
```

View

```
@section Title
{
    write title
}
```

**One thing i could suggest to improve default functionality**

```
@{
    string pageTitle = @ViewBag.Title ?? "Title Not Set";
}
<title>@pageTitle</title>
```

So whenever you forget to add it in viewbag, the page will display title= `Title Not Set`

Creating a base class then making all your controllers inherit from that base-class can also be done. But I think its taking so much of pain for `title`.

Comment: Just to clarify(I was not thinking of a default controller base class, I was thinking that you could create your own derived baseclass for the view (which I think razor let's you do) and expose a PageTitle property on this class which the view can assign and the layout can render)

Comment: I like this `@ViewBag.Title ?? "Default"` approach. It can be moved to _ViewStart.cshtml and you can set defaults here for all shared properties.

Comment: @soren.enemaerke : suppose you created a base-class for views to handle page title, probably inside your views you would set title like this @{this.pageTitle="New Title";} , while with default functionality you could set title like @{ ViewBag.Title = "New Title";}. There is not much difference in syntax.  One more benefit you get with this code ViewBag.Title="something", you can set title inside view or in controller, both will work.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since this seems to sum of the general feel of the answers: (1) dynamic is not evil and (2) you could do some slight improvements

Comment: Nice suggestion on using a section!

Answer (score 7):

ViewBag for title is perfectly fine (I'd even say it is the purpose of having ViewBag) - dynamic is not the absolute evil. "Title" is well known, unlikely to change and even predefined in view templates. I personally use following title:

```
<title>@(ViewBag.Title == null ? string.Empty : ViewBag.Title + " | ")Site Name</title>
```

If you are worried about mistyping `ViewBag.Title` you can make it strong type by creating custom `WebViewPage` but you will still have to use `ViewBag` or maybe `HttpContext.Items` inside that strongly typed property because there are multiple instances of `WebViewPage` created during rendering IIRC.

I'd recommend to stick with `ViewBag`, creating own `WebViewPage` because of this seems like overkill - even creating single property on it if you already have custom `WebViewPage` is in my opinion just worthless complication - and that comes from person that is often overengineering things.

Comment: Or just `<title>@(ViewBag.Title ?? ViewBag.Title + " | ")Site Name</title>` to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: @schaermu your suggestion doesn't work, it results in `| Site Name` if the Title property has not been set.

Answer (score 3):

I also do not use the ViewBag, at all.

At the top of _Layout.shtml ...

```
@model <YourWebAppNameSpace>.Models.Base.EveryPageViewModel
```

In _Layout.shtml ...

```
<title>@Model.Title</title>
```

In your Model ...

```
/// <summary>
/// Index View Model
/// </summary>
public class IndexViewViewModel : EveryPageViewModel {

}
```

In EveryPageViewModel

```
/// <summary>
/// Every Page View Model
/// </summary>
public abstract class EveryPageViewModel {
    /// <summary>
    /// Title
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sub Title
    /// </summary>
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller action

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Index
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var model = new IndexViewViewModel();
        model.Title = "Home";
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to create a PageTitle ActionFilter attributes rather than editing individual ViewBags

Usage: keep the view the same

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

For controller-wide page title:

```
[PageTitle("Manage Users")]
public class UsersController : Controller {
    //actions here
}
```

For individual views:

```
public class UsersController : Controller {
    [PageTitle("Edit Users")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
          //method here
    }
}
```

Attribute Code:

```
public class PageTitleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _pageTitle;
    public PageTitleAttribute(string pageTitle)
    {
        _pageTitle = pageTitle;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.ViewBag.Title = _pageTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Easy to manage and works like a charm.

Comment: The page title should be set in the view and not the controller.

Comment: Should it? Suppose you reuse a view for uploading different types of files? E.g. MyFiles/UploadExcel, MyFiles/UploadCsv...

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, I think this case is an acceptable use of `ViewBag`. It is limited to a "well-known" property, and it likely won't cause any problems in the future. In the end, it is all about being pragmatic and finding a way to be as quick as possible. Having a base class where you need to set the title would in my opinion be too much code to be worth the type safety.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that as long as it's only the Title you want to set, it's ok to use the ViewBag. Well, maybe not only - at most 2-3 properties.

But if you start to see you're setting more and more (common) properties in every controller action, I would go with a strongly typed "ViewModelBase class". But it's just me.

Answer (score 1):

we prefer strong title setting.. few sample from our BaseController class. (Page defines encapsulated view modal)

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
{
    if (model is Page)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = ((Page)model).Title;
        //HACK: SEO
        //TODO: SEO
    }
    return base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using ViewBag.Title = "My Title";

All you are doing is use a dynamic property.

The question is really where the information should be "declared".

Ie, where is it most accessible for the purposes at hand.

If it is on a per page basis, then that is the right place.

If, however, the title of the page can be derived from the Model, then you should do that.

In this case, I would probably use a base class for the ViewModel that you use, and create a PageTitle property there that contains the logic to derive the page title from properties in the Model.

So:

```
<title>Model.PageTitle</title>
```

In summary, horses for courses and don't be afraid of using dynamic properties... so long as you understand what they are and what they do.