# ASP.NET Core 6.0 with Hot Reload: Error when manipulating ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hot-reload

i have a fresh **ASP.NET Core 6.0** MVC Application.

The Controller Action writes some data in the ViewBag.

When i change some ViewBag Elements the Page is reloaded in the Browser with this error:

`RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'test'`

Steps:

1. In the Controller Action: `ViewBag.test="first test";`
2. Rebuild Soulution -> page loads fine
3. Change to `ViewBag.test="second test";`
4. Page auto reloads with the error
5. Rebuild Solution -> working fine again

This is my launchSettings.json:

```
"watch run": {
    "commandName": "Executable",
    "executablePath": "dotnet.exe",
    "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
    "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "hotReloadEnabled": true,
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7033;http://localhost:5033"
},
```

All Nuget Packages are updated.

Comment: Found this "solution": dont use ViewBag, use ViewData, but is there no real solution?

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37288

Comment: Looks like it's an open bug which wasn't fixed in time for the release: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59494 - the only "real" solution is to wait for that bug to be fixed.

Comment: ViewBag and ViewData are the same thing. If you want to try other changes, you can take a look at this post, which may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862367/in-a-simple-viewbag-title-getting-a-runtimebinderexception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a simple Viewbag.Title, getting a RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862367/in-a-simple-viewbag-title-getting-a-runtimebinderexception)

Comment: @jess No. maybe the Release of dotnet 7 will change the hoteload problem with ViewBag.

Answer (score 3):

You encountered a bug which is aimed to be fixed with NET8 --> https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59494 (Thanks, Richard!)

The problem may occur when you use the hot-reload feature of VS2022.

Quick fix: Stop debugging and re-start your application.